Protecting filling a buffer that is read from SRAM in STM32F429I
I'm trying to read a buffer from bus system using stm32F4, on falling interrupt. The problem is I need to process the data in main loop, and I don't need any latency, The falling interrupt, occurs at 500ns, and I don't want to miss any data. So disabling enabling an interrupt wouldn't be beneficial here.
I'm looking for a way to reduce latency, and not miss any interrupt.
Here is my approach:
In Main Loop:
    while (1)
    {
        if(iowr_set)
        {
            iowr_set = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
              {
                  processData(aRxBuffer[i]);
              }

        }
}

Interrupt:
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {


    if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_6) { // IORD

        HAL_SRAM_Read_16b(&hsram1, (uint32_t *)(SRAM_BANK_ADDR + WRITE_READ_ADDR), aRxBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

        iowr_set = 1;
    }
}

Declarations:
#define BUFFER_SIZE         ((uint32_t)0x0100)
#define WRITE_READ_ADDR     ((uint32_t)0x0800)

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SRAM_HandleTypeDef hsram1;
FMC_NORSRAM_TimingTypeDef SRAM_Timing;

/* Read/Write Buffers */
volatile uint16_t aRxBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];


You could use two alternating buffers. One is read into while processing the content of the other. So volatile uint16_t aRxBuffer[2][BUFFER_SIZE];

If my calculations are correct, if you run the CPU at 180 MHz (the max supported on this chip), each clock cycle is ~5.5ns. Which means you can do ~90 instructions in 500ns if each instruction took one clock cycle. And you need to read and process 256 bytes (or 64 uint32) in that time. Are you sure this is even possible?

@pmacfarlane You are correct with the analysis, What should I do to solve that issue please ? I meant processing part

@WeatherVane What If I'm processing just a single variable, not a buffer, due to processing constraints

@pmacfarlane I wonder with your analysis, that the FMC_SRAM sample has 256 bytes, and they do the same processing, without double buffering though...

Same thing: use alternate variables, it's usually worth buffering the data between ISR and reader. But however you do it, as pmacfarlane writes, you need to be able to handle the throughput. I guess the more data you read per interrupt, the more efficient it will be: fewer interrupts (traded off by the typical need to keep the interrupt response time to a minimum).

@WeatherVane but what about his analysis? so I should increase the buffer_size or decrease it

It's a trade-off with other parts of the program. How long can the program tolerate disabled interrupts? There may be other interrupts that need to function. But look at pmac's timing. However it is done, you need to handle the total throughput of data. If you can't, then you need to reduce the data input rate.

@WeatherVane I can't reduce input data rate, sorry but I didn't understand what is total throughput of data, How can I handle that

You need to read and process 64 32-bit values in 90 instructions. I don't know what "process" entails for you, but even reading the values in that time will be difficult. You could unroll a loop and maybe just keep up, assuming you did no processing at all. Basically it seems like this will be impossible. If you need this data rate, you need a (much) faster MCU.

Forget processing the values... Assuming 16-bit SRAM databus (from HAL_SRAM_Read_16b), in best possible circumstances you physically can't transfer 128 16-bit values in 90 HCLK cycles.
So the only way this is even possible is 32 bit bus, double-buffer DMA from the bus (without interrupts to restart it - not sure that is even possible), somehow avoid all/almost all internal bus arbitrage delays (separate code, CPU buffer and DMA buffer into SRAM1/2/3 and hope for the best), and then you left with 90 cycles to process the data - so maybe you can xor them all but not much more than that...

We need to know how and what is filling the SRAM. (e.g.) At time T1, the SRAM starts filling. At T2, the SRAM is full, and an interrupt is generated. All that time between T1 and T2 is wasted by the processor when it could be pulling in the data. After T2, does the filler immediately start filling byte 0 again? If so, this is a race condition. How are the filler/sender and the arm processor synchronizing things? You're using HAL's *_16b function. The *_32b may be twice as fast.

AFAICT, there is a DMA version: *_DMA. Using it, the processor cycles spent transferring from SRAM to main RAM are available for processing the data, rather than merely transferring it. That is, processing can overlap the transfer. But, at best, the processor speed is on the edge as far as being fast enough to keep up with the data, even with these tricks/tweaks.

Your STM32F429 can run at a maximum clock speed of 180MHz. This means that, assuming every instruction takes one clock cycle, you can execute 180 instructions in 1us, or 90 instructions in 500ns.
Your goal is to process 256 bytes in 500ns, or 64 32-bit words. So you need to be able to process 64 words in 90 instructions.
Let's imagine that you just wanted to read those words out of memory in that time. So let's simplify your code down to just this:
#include <stdint.h>

void read_data(uint32_t * data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 256 / sizeof(uint32_t); ++i)
    {
        volatile uint32_t datum = data[i];
        // No processing
    }
}

Could this code even read 64 words in 90 instructions? Probably not. It seems like a naive approach like this will require about 4 instructions per word. https://godbolt.org/z/MarW37qvq
You could unroll the loop and maybe, just maybe, be able to read the data out of RAM at the required speed. But this is with no processing being done at all.
On top of all that, you have a call to HAL_SRAM_Read_16b(), which in itself will probably take hundreds if not thousands of clock cycles. And you are using interrupts, which add even more overhead.
What you are trying to do is basically impossible. You'll need to reduce the data rate, or live with missing some of the data.
